VBA Copy/Paste to multiple specific cells on next free row
EDIT: Code adjusted to current half working version. Issue now is the 'layering' of paste actions though as shown in the image.
I've got a lot of good solutions from this site so I thought I'd see if the hive mind can help me with an odd-ish one. I'm not great at VBA, learning a lot though so here goes.
I have set of values on sheet 1 (range("E16:E20")) which I would like to split up and paste into columns E, G, I, K and M when I activate a button (which will also clear those cells ready for the next input. I.e. on the button press the value in "E16" needs to go into "E7", "E17" into "G7", "E18" into "I7" etc. The catch is it needs to be the next empty cell down. I.e. E16->E7, then E16->E8, E16->E9 and so on.
Sub LMI_NB1()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim copySheet As Worksheet
  Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
  
  'Sheet to copy from
    Set copySheet = Worksheets("Weekly Resin Shear Trials")
  'Sheet to paste to
    Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("84LMI NB1 Data")
  
  'Sample Data copy
    copySheet.Range("E16:E25").Copy
    
  pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  
  'Shear Category copy
    copySheet.Range("F16:F25").Copy
  
  pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
  'Date copy
    copySheet.Range("I4").Copy
  
  pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  
  'Operator copy
    copySheet.Range("I5").Copy
  
  pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 25).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  
  'Log No. & Expiry copy
    copySheet.Range("E13:E14").Copy
  
  pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  
End Sub

The rough code I have so far is above but if ANYTHING is in that row it puts the result to the next row down, creating a diagonal line of results instead (see image). I would like all the results from that button press on the same line but the next free line if that makes sense.
Picture for clarity:

I think it's something to do with the pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp) section but I can't get my head around it.

The code you have shown already copy the E16:E25 range to Ex:Nx. What will be with this? If there are empty cells in the source sheet the next copy will mix the target sheet. It doesn't copy always to a new line the parts. Are you sure, that this program generates the result on the screenshot? Mainly there is no pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp) section in it.

Copy Transpose Column


The following exploits the fact that each next destination cell is two cells to the right of the previous.

Main
Sub LMI_NB1()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook conataining this code
   
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Weekly Resin Shear Trials")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("E16:E20")
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("84LMI NB1 Data")
    Dim dcell As Range:
    Set dcell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    CopyTransposeValues srg, dcell, 2
  
End Sub

Help
Sub CopyTransposeValues( _
        ByVal sourceRange As Range, _
        ByVal destinationCell As Range, _
        Optional ByVal DestinationColumnOffset As Long = 1)
       
    Dim scell As Range, dColumnOffset As Long
    
    For Each scell In sourceRange.Cells
        destinationCell.Offset(, dColumnOffset).Value = scell.Value
        dColumnOffset = dColumnOffset + DestinationColumnOffset
    Next scell
    
End Sub


The following will handle random destination columns in the same row.

Main
Sub LMI_NB2()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook conataining this code
   
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Weekly Resin Shear Trials")
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("84LMI NB1 Data")
    
    Dim dRow As Long:
    dRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    CopyColumnValues sws, "E16", dws, dRow, Array("E", "G", "I", "K", "M")
  
End Sub

Help
Sub CopyColumnValues( _
        ByVal sws As Worksheet, _
        ByVal SourceFirstCellAddress As String, _
        ByVal dws As Worksheet, _
        ByVal DestinationRow As Long, _
        DestinationColumns As Variant)
       
    Dim dcol As Long: dcol = LBound(DestinationColumns) - 1
    Dim CellsCount As Long: CellsCount = UBound(DestinationColumns) - dcol
    
    Dim scell As Range
     
    For Each scell In sws.Range(SourceFirstCellAddress).Resize(CellsCount).Cells
        dcol = dcol + 1
        dws.Cells(DestinationRow, DestinationColumns(dcol)).Value = scell.Value
    Next scell
    
End Sub

